# If X is the sister of Y and Y is the sister of Z then X need not be the sister of Z. How is this relation correct?

Tags: relations

This is a statement from the *Sets and Relations* chapter of **Discrete Mathematics.** It is about the relation between the elements of a set, let say A. So, the relation R = 'is a sister of' where the following statement is defined to be true: "It is not transitive, because if X is the sister of Y and Y is the sister of Z then X need not be the sister of Z."

This is a bit subtle, can you see why?

Reference: Grossman,Peter (2009), Discrete mathematics for computing. 3 ed. Houndmills:Palgrave Macmillan. (316 s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's subtle about it? You just consider the case in which $Z=X$. No woman is her own sister.

Comment: X, Y, and Z are three distinct elements.

Comment: Consider this, if Xennix is the sister of Yennix and Yennix is the sister of Zorba then why can't Xennix be the sister of Zorba, be he male or female.

Comment: The sentence “It is not transitive, because if $X$ is the sister of $Y$ and $Y$ is the sister of $Z$ then $X$ need not be the sister of $Z$.” does **not** contain the assumption that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are distinct.

Comment: Then why do they used different variables?

Comment: In order to cover every possibility. But if I say that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, I am not asserting that $a\neq b$. I am saying that that equality holds for *every* $a$ and *every* $b$.

Comment: I get it, now. But it was vague

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Perhaps you could upvote my question if it was worthy of asking.